# How do I debug two android devices simultaneously in Eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging

I have a multiplayer game which should be tested on two devices at the same time, if possible, with debugging.

Can eclipse do this?  If so, how?

Comment: have you tested to debug the game on two machines? so that you have two computers running ecplise and debuging?

Comment: I don't have 2 machines to do so, evenso i do not want to copy the eclipse project to another machine every testrun. I use TFS for source control but constantly checking in /out is still time consuming. I't would be perfect if eclipse can do it.
Also I've thought about using a virtual machine for a second eclipse install. But, as I said this is far from optimal.

Comment: indeed it is. just a idea from the box :)

Comment: Well it is a solution to my problem, be it not the most optimal.
Maybe in the future when there are more developers working on the project this will be the way to go.

Comment: Ideally you'd want to ask "How can I do this?", since the answer would be "You can't" or "This is how...". The available answers to your current question are "No" or "Yes". Just a thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to select each device in the **DDMS** perspective to get the **LogCat** output from the relevant device because that window is on a per device basis, but other than that there's nothing preventing you from debugging multiple instances at once.

Comment: Sounds great, I will try it as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: I used this a lot while testing the multiplayer aspects of my game, you kind of have to get used to hitting breakpoints on different running instances but the **Debug** view is your friend for that.

Comment: hmm i first need to find out why my breakpoints are not hitting while my game is running :) If you are used to vs2010 eclipse can be such a ****